# if statement in ruby

Tags: ruby

How does this statement work?

```
if not a==b
  puts "amit"
else
  puts "ramit"
end
```

Could anybody tell me the use of `not` operator here?

Comment: To properly format code please indent it by 4 spaces or use the code-button in the toolbar to do so. Otherwise the code shows up all in one line like it does now (which in this case makes it look like a syntax error cause the line breaks are not optional here).

Comment: if you just highlight your code and press 'control key' and letter 'K' together, it will automatically indent it for you

Answer (score 3):

`if not a==b` is equal to `if !(a==b)`, `if a!=b`, `unless a==b` or `unless not a!=b`

If you don't know this I would recommend reading "The Well-Grounded Rubyist" from David A. Black

Answer (score 3):

a == b returns true if they are equal.

The not operator inverts the answer, so:

not a == b returns true if they are NOT equal.

Answer (score 2):

See here [Ruby Logical Operators](http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Ruby.html) for a discussion.

`not a==b` is the same as  `!(a==b)` they are both acceptable.

Comment: step i did nt get what u wrote if you just highlight your code and press 'control key' and letter 'K' together, it will automatically indent it for you what does that mean